# Variable not defined, also it is defined in a function in a separate Pythonfile

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables, nameerror

i'm a beginner with Python and want to write a programm where i have a main program and several subprograms.

The problem i have is the following:

```
import func_betriebssysteme
func_betriebssysteme.betriebssystem()
    
# Schritt 1

print("Betriebssystem:",betriebssystem_use)
```

That is the code of "func_betriebssysteme", my separat py.file:

```
def betriebssystem():
import sys

temp_a = sys.platform

global betriebssystem_use
betriebssystem_use = str(temp_a)
```

And that is the errormessage:

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6860/1431564812.py in ()
>       9 # Schritt 1
>      10 
> ---> 11 print("Betriebssystem:",betriebssystem_use)
>
> NameError: name 'betriebssystem_use' is not defined
> ```

If i have the function betriebssystem() directly at the beginning of the code and not in a separat file, it works.

What do i do wrong?

Edit 21.3.2023

Hello again,

I haven't really made any progress yet.

I'm still feeling my way along, bit by bit. In the process, I noticed the following.

When I run this code, I get a name error bsuse not defined.

```
from func_ausschr.func_betriebssysteme import *
betriebssystem()
print(bsuse)
```

That is the code in the file func_auschr.func_betriebssysteme

```
def betriebssystem():
    
    import sys
    global bsuse
    temp = sys.platform
    bsuse = temp
```

If I run the code again directly, the variable is resolved with win32.

What is going wrong here?

By the way, I use Python3.10 in Jupyter-Notebook (Visual Studio Code) for testing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: No, I'm sorry. The files are all in the same directory. I created a blank __init__.py  in this folder. But it don't worked.
Than i copied the both files (main-py and function-py) in the Python-folder. I don't works to.

Comment: I found this [link]https://iq-inc.com/importerror-attempted-relative-import/ and changed my structure of the directorys.
Now i have a directory in which is my main-program and a subdirectory with an an empty '__init.py__ file' where my modules are stored. I understood this as the meaning of using a package.
In my main code i import the module now with "import func_ausschr.func_betriebssysteme". But i get the same errormessage "NameError: name 'betriebssystem_use' is not defined"